# Issue with position:fixed on Windows Phone

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, mobile, compatibility

I use position:fixed on the bottom bar (it's a fixed contact menu).

```
<style>
.bottom-menu {
width:100%
height:50px
background-color:#e3e3e3;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0
}
</style>
<div class="bottom-menu">
some text and social icon
</div>
```

On Windows Phone with IE, there is an issue.

After 50% scrolling, my bottom-menu begins to vibrate, also slows down, and it takes a few seconds to return to bottom.

Comment: Which Windows Phone version are you using? Which IE version? I can't test it, because i have Android but maybe take a look at these: [fixed-footer](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/), [fixed-positioning in mobile browsers](http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the semicoloms after width:100% and height 50px
Also there is no position:fixed ? You should post the whole code :)

```
<style>
.bottom-menu {
width:100%;
height:50px;
background-color:#e3e3e3;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0
}
</style>
<div class="bottom-menu">
some text and social icon
</div>
```

Also make sure you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the beginning of your documents because this also can cause troubles in some browsers.
Also the ; at the  End of an CSS Document in unnecessary :)